# Como puedo solucionar el warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type"

Tags: c, puntero-a-función

estoy haciendo este programa en C sobre señales, pero al compilarlo me sale este warning:

> practica8.c: In function ‘main’:
>
> practica8.c:18:17: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> act.sa_handler = tratar_alarma; /*Funcion a ejecutar*/

¿saben cómo puedo solucionarlo?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void *tratar_alarma(void)
    {
        printf("Alarma activada\n");
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        struct sigaction act;
        sigset_t mask;
        int pause(void);
        unsigned int alarm(unsigned int seconds);

        /*especifica el manejador*/
        act.sa_handler = tratar_alarma; /*Funcion a ejecutar*/
        act.sa_flags = 0;/*ninguna accion escifica*/

        /*Sebloquea la señal 3 SIGQUIT*/

        sigemptyset(&mask);
        sigaddset(&mask, SIGQUIT);
        sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);

        for(;;)
        {
            alarm(3);/*se arma el temporizador*/
            pause();/*se suspende el proceso hasta que se reciba la
        señal*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La respuesta es corta, no pasas el tipo de puntero que espera `sigaction::sa_handler` el cual es un puntero a función con un argumento de tipo `int` que retorna `void`.

Según [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigaction), la definición de `sa_handler` es la siguiente:

```
void (*sa_handler)(int);
```

Y le andas pasando:

```
void *(*similar_a_tratar_alarma)(void);
```

La solución: Cambia la definición de tu función `tratar_alarma` a la siguiente:

```
void tratar_alarma(int tipo) {
  // Haz algo con la alarma.
}
```

Y debería funcionar :)